# How to write a Groovy script to iterate block by block a log file for a particular field

Tags: groovy

So I've got logs that are in the following format:

```
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 123
UAN: 321
======================================================== END]
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 111
UAN: 222
======================================================== END]
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 343
UAN: 311
======================================================== END]
```

Is it possible to write a groovy script that lets you iterate through each block, that block being "Begin" and "End" and basically search for a particular UAN, and pon finding that uan, returning the messageID.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Faker faker = new Faker()

def fileName = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\log.txt";
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);

def uan= "222"

def logSection = faker.logExtractor().getSectionOfLog(uan, path);

log.info logSection
```

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do to iterate through a block instead of iterating line by line?

Thanks

Comment: Thats the thing, that tag doesn't do anything. It's something that's been programmatically added to separate the logs in a readable format, but I want iterate through these blocks and return messageID if there's a match with a uan

Comment: anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the typical and maximum size of the log file/s you are processing?

Comment: @RaviH I'm not too sure, but is that important?

Comment: Yes, it is important. For example - if it is a standalone program processing the logs once in a week it may be possible to load several mb's of file content in memory (in a String) and run regexp on it. On the other hand if it is a heavily used multi user web app then loading  more than few kb's (for sure not more than few hundred kb's) in memory can invite trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The below creates a map where you can look up the uan:

```
def str = '''\
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 123
UAN: 321
======================================================== END]
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 111
UAN: 222
======================================================== END]
======================================================== BEGIN]
MessageID: 343
UAN: 311
======================================================== END]'''

def map = str.readLines().collect { 
  it.trim()
}.findAll { 
  !it.startsWith('==') && (it.startsWith('MessageID') || it.startsWith('UAN'))
}.collect { 
  it.tokenize(':')[1].trim()
}.collate(2).collectEntries { 
  it.reverse() 
}

println(map['222'])
```

prints:

```
111
```

This makes a few assumptions about your log file format and is more intended as an example of how you can work with line based data.

Another approach would be to use the groovy string [eachMatch method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#eachMatch(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
str.eachMatch(/(?s)BEGIN.\s*(.+?)\s*=+ END/) { m -> 
  def (mid, uan) = m[1].readLines().collect { it.trim().tokenize(':')[1].trim() }
  println "messageId: $mid, uan: $uan"
}
```

prints:

```
messageId: 123, uan: 321
messageId: 111, uan: 222
messageId: 343, uan: 311
```